# Background Transparent When Inflating Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am inflating a view and I would like the `FrameLayout` to be transparent, I tried to set the `backgroundColor` but it's not working.

```
 @NonNull
    @Override
    public StoryTextFragment.StoryTextColorAdapter.LeagueLiveHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.color_picker_cell, parent, false);

        return new StoryTextFragment.StoryTextColorAdapter.LeagueLiveHolder(itemView);
    }
```

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:alpha="1"
    >

    <com.puzio.fantamaster.stories.CircleView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What is not working? The color is not set or any error? Did you set your custom color you're using correctly?

Comment: When the Recycler View renders the cell, the background is white and not transparent. If I put the alpha to the item view, the alpha is also reflected in the CircleView

Comment: And if you use `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` instead?

Comment: yes is the same, I already tried

Comment: @DavidVittori I think you should ask your boss :)

Comment: @DavidVittori I think you should have to check once recycle view first or background color of main layout so you can understand where is issue

Comment: ok thank you, yes the problem was in the underline view